# Use of Spring AOP on Async method

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, annotations, spring-aop

Is it possible to use @After and @Around with a `@Async` method?
I tried with both of the annotation like this:

```
@Override
@SetUnsetEditingFleet
public void modifyFleet(User user, FleetForm fleetForm) throws Exception{
    databaseFleetsAndCarsServices.modifyFleet(user, fleetForm);
}

@Around("@annotation(SetUnsetEditingFleet) && args(user, fleetForm)")
public void logStartAndEnd(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, User user, FleetForm fleetForm) throws Throwable{
    fleetServices.setEditingFleet(fleetForm.getIdFleet());
    for(Car car : carServices.findByFleetIdFleet(fleetForm.getIdFleet())){
        carServices.setEditingCar(car.getIdCar());   //Set cars associated with the fleet
    }  
    pjp.proceed();
    fleetServices.unSetEditingFleet(fleetForm.getIdFleet());     
    for(Car car : carServices.findByFleetIdFleet(fleetForm.getIdFleet())){
        carServices.unSetEditingCar(car.getIdCar());    //Unset cars associated with the fleet 
    }
}

@Override
@Async
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public void modifyFleet(User currentUser, FleetForm fleetForm) throws Exception {
    //method instructions
```

The after part is called before the method end. I tried also with the `@After` and `@Before` annotation and the result is the same.

Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: The method ended because the processing has been dispatched to a new thread. So for the calling code the method execution ended. So yes you can use it, but not what you want to use it for.

Comment: So only the `@Before` can be used, the `@After` part is called after the new thread start and not at the end of it. Is it correct?

Comment: NO it is called at the end of the method.. The method ends as soon as the thread starts. For the calling code the method execution is over.

Answer (score 1):

@After will not work correctly with @Async as the work has not completed yet. You can solve this by returning a CompletableFuture instead of void for your async method and handling any after logic with a callback method. Without testing here is an example:

```
    @Around("@annotation(AsyncBeforeAfter)")
    public void asyncBeforeAfter(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{
        // before work
        Object output = pjp.proceed();
        CompletableFuture future = (CompletableFuture) output;
        future.thenAccept(o -> {
           // after work
        });

    }

    @Override
    @Async
    @AsyncBeforeAfter
    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public CompletableFuture<String> modifyFleet(User currentUser, FleetForm fleetForm) throws Exception {
      return  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
           //method instructions
           return "done";
     });
    }
```